# jquery ajax send data double to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I took a normal javascript countdown and at the end of the countdown a ajax request should save the data to a database.

Okay this works but it saves the entry twice. Any suggestions on why it saves two times?

```
var countdown = <?php echo $aufendhalt;?>;
function count() 
{
    countdown = countdown - 1;
    if(document.getElementById("counter")) 
    {
        if(countdown <= 0)
        {
            // Funktion
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "N&auml;chste Kampagne wird geladen";
            var datastring = {
                ip: <?php echo json_encode($ip)?>,
                uid : <?php echo json_encode($uid) ?>,
                tan : <?php echo json_encode($tan) ?>,
                reload : <?php echo json_encode($reload) ?>,
                verdienst : <?php echo json_encode($verdienst)?>,
                preis : <?php echo json_encode($preis) ?>
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.php',
                data: datastring,
                //success: function(data){
                    // $('#result').html(data);
                //}
            }); 
        } 
        else  
        {
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = countdown;
        }
    }

    if(countdown >= 0) 
    {
        setTimeout("count()",1000);
    }
}

count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if(countdown >= 0) 
{
    setTimeout("count()",1000);
}
```

with this:

```
if(countdown > 0) 
{
    setTimeout("count()",1000);
}
```

Comment: reason for this is cause it calls the request one time on "bigger than" and the second for "is then" good to know

Comment: In your original code, if `countdown` equals zero, then you would execute the `count()` function one more time, thereby causing the AJAX call to be done twice.